# Enabling debug logging in Python

Tags: python, debugging, logging

Given this code I try to have log statements working but I am not able to. The documentation tells me that I do not have to set a level.

> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all
>   messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or
>   delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger).

But it did not work without. Therefore I tried to set it to debug. But still no luck.

```
"""
Experimental Port Fowarding
"""
import logging

def main(config):
    """ entry point"""

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log.debug("opening config file...")
    config_file = open(config, 'r')
    log.debug("config found!")
```

Comment: It's useful to have a complete example. If this is your whole program, the reason you're not seeing output is because you're not calling `main`

Comment: I am calling it through the REPL. Actually there is only `print(line)` missing for the loop over the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the logger writes to STDERR stream which usually prints to the console itself. 
Basically you can change the log file path by setting:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="YourFileName.log")
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 1):

The logger you are getting doesn't have any handlers. You can check this by doing `print(log.handlers)` and seeing the output is an empty list (`[]`).

The simplest way to use the logging library is something like this, where you call `logging.basicConfig` to set everything up, as shown in the [logging module basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial):

```
"""
Experimental Port Fowarding
"""
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def main(config):
    """ entry point"""

    logging.debug("opening config file...")
    config_file = open(config, 'r')
    logging.debug("config found!")

main('test.conf')
```

This works for me from outside and inside IPython.

If you want to avoid `basicConfig` for some reason you need to register a handler manually, like this:

```
import logging

def main(config):
    """ entry point"""

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Minimal change: add StreamHandler to display to stdout
    log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

    log.debug("opening config file...")
    config_file = open(config, 'r')
    log.debug("config found!")
```